# how to list/skip breakpoints in python debugger?

Tags: python, pdb

I'm using a vanilla python 3.7 installation and I've used following test code in a file, and ran it:

```
for k in range(10):
    print(k)
    breakpoint()
    print(k*10)
```

As expected the debugger prompt appeared. I've tried to list all breakpoints using [`b[reak]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-break) which is supposed to list all breakpoints. But this didn't print anything, so I think I must be making a mistake somewhere - can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

My goal was disabling this breakpoint for the future iterations, but to `disable` it I thought I need the number - is it maybe also possible to disable it without knowing the number?

Comment: I can't find anything telling that breakpoints set via `breakpoint()` will not by listed via `b` but you are right. Breakpoints set via `b` will be listed just fine.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it's a built-in function (python 3.7 and later)

Comment: @mkrieger1 Indeed it's a [built in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint).

Comment: @m02ph3u5 Actually I was wondering if I could skip a breakpoint set by `breakpoint()` in the future iterations for which I wanted to use `disable`, but obviously couldn't even find the number of the breakpoint.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that `breakpoint()` might be a misleading function name, because it seems that it doesn't behave the same as the breakpoints you set from within the debugging prompt. But I'd be happy if someone woud prove otherwise:)

Comment: As a hint, `b` also won't list breakpoints set via `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` directly - so no difference there. A 10-minute glance at pdb and bdb didn't reveal the difference between `break` and `set_trace` to me.

Comment: @m02ph3u5 Thanks for looking into this. As far as I know `breakpoint()` was intended to more or less replace `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` so this does not surprize me, but it is interesting that there is no obvious difference between `break` and `set_trace`!